# Connecting to a datomic-free instance hosted on EC2 from outside AWS?

Tags: clojure, amazon-ec2, datomic

I've installed and run cldwalker's datomic-free receipe https://github.com/cldwalker/datomic-free on an EC2 instance.

```
;=> System started datomic:free://{EC2 private IP address}:4334/<DB-NAME>, 
;   storing data in: data
```

My `free-transactor.properties` file looks like this:

```
protocol=free
host={EC2 private IP address}
port=4334
h2-port=4335
h2-web-port=4336
```

I want to connect the database from outside EC2:

```
(require '[datomic.api :as d]) 

(def uri "datomic:free://{EC2 public IP address}:4334/om_async?h2-
port=4335&h2-web-port=4336&aws_secret_key={xxx}&aws_access_key_id={yyy}")

(d/create-database uri)
```

But I get:

```
clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: Error communicating with HOST 
{EC2 private IP address} on PORT 4334 :: {:timestamp 1418304487036, 
:host "{EC2 private IP address}", :version "0.9.5078", :port 4334, 
:username "{XXX}", :peer-version 2, :alt-host nil, :password "{YYY}", 
:encrypt-channel true}
```

What should I do to make this work?

**UPDATE:**

I have found the "Free Transactor on EC2" thread in the Datomic Google Group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/datomic/wBRZNyHm03o/0SdNhqjF27wJ

Does this means I can only connect to Datomic-free if my app run on the same server?

Would I have the same problem (not being able to access db from outside server) if I get Datomic-free hosted on linode or digitalocean?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Have you checked your EC2 Security Group settings to make sure that port 4335 are exposed to public network?

Comment: I cannot remember the reason but I recall that sometimes the port numbers might change and shift a bit

Comment: @daniula Thank you. It did work but now I'm getting this error: "java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not find om_async in catalog" Any idea? I update my post above.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem ("Error communicating with HOST 
on PORT 4334") and all I had to do was restart my computer, strangely enough. Something with the ports being tied up after having launched a local transactor, I think. Then again, you probably already tried that.

Comment: I've tried that back then without much success. You say you have installed and set up on AWS a Datomic Free instance and can use it in an app hosted locally on your computer? That is great! If, by pure chance, you would be ready to share the steps you went through in a blog post or github readme, it would be very valuable :-D

Comment: I may just do that :D But first, one thing I noticed is that you wrote "protocol=free". I never did that, even though I'm not using a paid version of Datomic (I'm using Datomic Pro Starter Edition, actually, so maybe none of this is helpful to you). Any reason you're using "protocol=free"? It could be messing up the connection.

Comment: I also never had to use h2-port or h2-web-port in the address.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I should have tried the Pro version. I'm not sure it is always free though. (1 year?) Anyway, thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: No problem! Sorry I couldn't help you more :)

Answer (score 0):

To allow remote peers access to embedded storage you must do three things:

- choose two passwords for the embedded storage
- set the storage-access property
- add a password to the connection URI used by peers

Take a look at this [link](https://docs.datomic.com/on-prem/configuring-embedded.html)